# Running SAS in Access using VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, sas

After reading this: http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi30/044-30.pdf

I decided to try running a SAS program with Access, but I am having some trouble with the VBA.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Command_Click()
Dim olesas as Object
Dim Data_ID as String 'note this is the name of a txtbox in my form
dd_id=Data_ID.Value 'here is where my error is
Set olesas=CreateObject("SAS.Application")
olesas.Submit (" %let DD_ID=" & dd_id & "; %inc 'SASMACRO'") 'didn't feel like typing whole inc statement here
olesas.Visable=True
olesas.Quit
Set olesas=Nothing
End Sub
```

I get an error when I try to set the parameter in the form as a variable in VBA that will then be turned into a macro variable in SAS. Any ideas?

Comment: `dd_id = Data_ID.Value` is not dimmed - do you have Options Explicit set?  (That's a VBA line, so it has nothing to do with SAS yet.)  You also aren't properly referencing your txtbox - I think you need to dim `dd_id` as string, and not `Data_ID`, as you want that to be your textbox.  You should look up how to reference textboxes - I don't recall the exact access object model but it'll be something like Application.Textboxes.Textbox("Data_ID") or something around that.

Comment: Now that I read the paper, that's how they do it... I'm an excel VBA person but to me that would be very ... odd ... to dim a string and magically get a textbox value from it.

Comment: Thanks @Joe. I will look investigate this further.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Data_ID as String 'note this is the name of a txtbox in my form
dd_id=Data_ID.Value 'here is where my error is
```

By dimming data_ID as String, that has no reference to the txtbox on your form. What you have done here create a variable named data_ID (which has no value assigned to it) and tried to use an undeclared variable named dd_ID.  You would want to do it like;

```
dim dd_id as String
dd_id = me.Data_ID.Value ' assuming data_id is the name of your txtbox
```

If your txtbox is on the same form as your button then you can use Me. to reference that form's controls. If the txtbox is on another form, you would need to explicitly reference by Forms!yourFormName!Data_ID.Value

One other thing it's always good practice to name your controls appropriately, so for your txtbox name the control txtDataID and your button btnNameHere etc - makes things a bit easier in the long run.

HTH